# Dereferencing void pointer

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I was reading a guide to threads programming using `pthreads.h` library when i encountered this kind of code. Not exactly this, but the thing is in `void *` pointer dereferencing.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(void * x) {
    printf("%d\n", (int) x);
}

int main() {
    int x = 10;
    func((void *) x);
    return 0;
}
```

Why i can just use

```
(int) x
```

for dereferncing `void *` pointer in `func`?

I thought it has to be something like this:

```
* ((int *) x)
```

Similar question about this line of code in main function:

```
func((void *) x);
```

I don't even get address of `x` variable here.

Comment: You might see this technique in very old code, or in new code written by people who don't realize C has improved since the 1970s.  The `10` is being "transported" as a different type. This technique is not portable and may fail on various systems.

Comment: Please note that commonly when talking about something like `void * p` one would call `p` a `void`-pointer (a pointer to `void`). Taking this latter convention into account wording "*p is a `void *`-pointer*" would identify `p` to be a `void ** p`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Passing an integer of type `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t` would be fine.

Comment: @alk or just `int` since that is the type of the variable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're not dereferencing `x` when doing `(int) x`. You just convert a pointer (which is more or less an address) to an `int`, which is a number representation, which might be printed.

**EDIT**: By the way, converting `x` to an signed integer (`int`) should give you a compiler warning. The *more* proper way to deal with this is

```
printf("%p\n", x);
```

`%p` is a special format specifier, which interprets the thing handed to `printf` as a pointer (address specifier), printing it in hex, which is often more useful when dealing with addresses.

**EDIT2**: By the way, too, to dereference `x`, you'd first have to give it a meaningful pointer type:

```
char a = *((char*)x);
```

will set `a` to the character that is stored at the address that `p` contains.

Comment: It means i don't even save the address in void * x argument? I use pointer variable for sending value not address?

Comment: @Joey74: a pointer really just contains the address of the variable/data it points at (hence the name, *pointer*). In this particular (not very typical) case, the pointer is only used as an address-containing variable.

Comment: @Joey74: In short, yes.

Answer (score 2):

The function `func` just prints the address of pointer `x`.

If you want to see `func` in action, do this:

```
void func(void * x) {
    printf("%d\n", (int) x);
}

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        void *x = malloc(100);
        func(x);
        free(x);
    }
}
```

This code will allocate 5 memory blocks, and print their addresses.

Comment: Assuming func would spawn a thread and pass x to it you do not want to free x outside func as long as you did not made sure the thread isn't using the memory referenced by x anymore.

Comment: I meant `func` as defined in the question, not any function. I've included it in the answer now. The point is really just to illustrate why one would want to convert a pointer to integer.

Comment: I like this answer. It illustrates things well.

Answer (score 1):

In practice, the data passed to a thread function with `pthread_create` should either be a static data (but then you can create only one thread using it, since it is not reentrant) or a heap-allocated data, or a pointer converted to something else. If it is a local data, it would be destroyed before the started thread finishes (unless you take specific precautions, e.g. calling `pthread_join` in the *same* function that called `pthread_create`).

Here are some examples, assuming a global `pthread_t thr;` variable and the following thread function

```
void *run_thread(void*p) {
   int* pi = p;
   (*pi)++;
   printf("in thread data=%d\n", *pi);
   return pi;
}
```

#### one thread with static data

Recall that with static data your code is not reentrant, and you could only have *one* thread using that data.

```
void run_my_thread(void) {
   static int x;
   int err = pthread_create(&thr, NULL, run_thread, &x);
   if (err) 
     { fprintf(stderr, "pthread failed %d (%s)\n", err, strerror(err));
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }
   do_something_else();
   void* res = NULL;
   pthread_join(thr, &res);
   if (res) printf("got %d from thread\n", *(int*)res);
 }
```

A common pattern might be to have a static array of e.g. 5 data elements, and run exactly 5 threads, each processing its own element in that static array.

#### thread with heap allocated data

```
void run_my_thread(void) {
   int *pi = malloc(sizeof(int));
   if (!pi) {perror("malloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
   *pi = 42;
   int err = pthread_create(&thr, NULL, run_thread, pi);
   if (err) 
     { fprintf(stderr, "pthread failed %d (%s)\n", err, strerror(err));
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }
   do_something_else();
   void* res = NULL;
   pthread_join(thr, &res);
   if (res) printf("got %d from thread\n", *(int*)res);
   free (pi), pi = NULL;
 }
```

Sometimes, but this is ugly, you might pass a casted `inptr_t` *value* (not the pointer to it) to `pthread_create`.

#### thread with `intptr_t` data

Of course it has no sense to use it as a dereferenced pointer in the thread routine which might be:

```
 void*run_thread_int(void*p) {
   intptr_t i = (intptr_t)p;
   printf("i=%d\n", i);
   return NULL;
 }
```

then you could code

```
 void run_my_thread_int(void) {
    intptr_t j=53;
   int err = pthread_create(&thr, NULL, run_thread_int, (void*)j);
   if (err) 
     { fprintf(stderr, "pthread failed %d (%s)\n", err, strerror(err));
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }
   do_something_else();
   pthread_join(thr, NULL);
 }
```

A pragmatic way to think of `pthread_create` is to see the thread function as getting a single argument in a machine register which can hold a pointer (or an `intptr_t` with the trick above).

Most of the time you'll **use a *heap-allocated* `struct`** (packing *several* values) **as the argument to your thread function**.

Comment: "*... should [...] be a static data*" I feel this is worded to strict. Using static data would make the function un-reintrant and un-thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

You are not casting a pointer to an integer to a void pointer when you do `(void *) x` - you are casting an integer to a void pointer. You now have a void pointer whose points to an address equal to the value of the integer `x`. Inside your function definition, you reverse this and cast it back to an integer.